# How to use two firebase projects in single Android app at same time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need two firebase projects for single Android app. One project is for users, and other is for Admins. I'm using the admins firebase project for some reasons.

Now I need to connect these two projects in admin app, and I want to add or modify firestore data at a time in both firebase projects from admin app.

How to get instances of two firebase project at single time in Android?

I have seen some stackoverflow questions regarding this but they are not getting two instances at same time.

Can anyone please answer my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to change your default app. Connect your app to the main firebase project normally. Also, register your app with the second firebase project. Now instead of importing the `google-services.json` file to the android project directly create a Singleton class like below and replace it with your second firebase project details.

```
public class MySecondaryProject {
    private static FirebaseApp INSTANCE;

    public static FirebaseApp getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = getSecondProject(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static FirebaseApp getSecondProject(Context context) {
        FirebaseOptions options1 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setApiKey("AI...gs")
                .setApplicationId("1:5...46")
                .setProjectId("my-project-id")
                // setDatabaseURL(...)      // in case you need firebase Realtime database
                // setStorageBucket(...)    // in case you need firebase storage MySecondaryProject
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options1, "admin");
        return FirebaseApp.getInstance("admin");
    }
}
```

Now wherever you need this second project instance you can use like below.

```
  FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); //- DEFAULT PROJECT
  FirebaseFirestore secondDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(MySecondaryProject.getInstance(this)); // - SECOND PROJECT
```

You must need to follow the singleton pattern to avoid duplicate instances otherwise the app will crash. you can use both the instances simulteneously.

For more details some useful links

- [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application)
- [Some Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69660332/16281582)
- [some other source form itzone.com.vn](https://itzone.com.vn/en/article/use-multiple-firebase-projects-in-1-android-app/)

I think it will be the perfect answer of your question.

Comment: I had spent much time finding this working solution. **If this helps, upvote my answer.**

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't.

Instead of one project for admins and one for users, you want to have role based access control on a single project. For example, admins can delete files, whilst users cannot.

There is a [full guide to role based access available in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access), along with a few variations. Your rules may end up looking something like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /stories/{story} {
        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
        }

        function getRole(rsc) {
          // Read from the "roles" map in the resource (rsc).
          return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
        }

        function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
          // Determine if the user is one of an array of roles
          return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
        }

        function isValidNewStory() {
          // Valid if story does not exist and the new story has the correct owner.
          return resource == null && isOneOfRoles(request.resource, ['owner']);
        }

        // Owners can read, write, and delete stories
        allow write: if isValidNewStory() || isOneOfRoles(resource, ['owner']);

         match /comments/{comment} {
            // ...
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jake Lee. I had an idea on implementation of role based users with firebase custom climes. But in my case another project not only for Admins role. It acts as a data backup of admin created app content, and to store some extra confidential details about that specific content. Also for some extra reasons.

Comment: Nothing you have stated requires a separate project.  Security rules & roles handle all the confidentiality - I can state this quite conclusively - I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have standard user and admins, just use [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). Don't write the the roles to Firestore.

It will make the setup much easier and will not cost you in expensive `get` calls in your rules.