# How to switch the Firebase Instances at run time in android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason, I need to use two firebase projects in a single android app. Now I need to access those two Firebase projects Firestore Databases at the same time. But I had seen in some StackOverflow questions that this is not possible to get both the Firebase projects instances at same time.

My requirement is to read data from first Firebase project Database, now the data will be processed(some operations or changes) in the android app. After that I need to upload that processed data to Second Firebase project Database.

So I need to switch the Firebase project Instances at run time according to the requirement. Is it possible to use two instances in single android app?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access multiple Firebase projects from within a single Android application see https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.But you can create multiple buckets and data into it.This will act as different database.You can then switch the project buckets and proceed with it.But I will not prefer you to use different buckets instead use 1 bucket with different collection names!